2d arrays in etherscan
How to Pass 2D Arrays in Etherscan Contract Interaction?
I am encountering difficulties when trying to pass 2D arrays to a smart contract through Etherscan's interface. While the function executes as expected in Remix with the given input, I cannot replicate this success on Etherscan due to input formatting issues.
Function Example:
The smart contract function I'm trying to interact with expects a 2D array of integers as an input parameter.
What I've Tried:

Directly passing the array in the format [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] which works in Remix.
Various JSON-like formats such as {"exampleArray": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]} and simple nested arrays without JSON structure, but none were accepted by Etherscan.


Can you share the function that you're trying to call ?

here it is `function createPBatch(
uint[][] memory chainIds,
string[][] memory dstAddresses,
uint[] memory dstChainId,
uint[] memory dstAssetId,
string[] memory dstAddress,
uint[] memory srcAssetId,
address[] memory srcAddress,
uint[] memory timelock,
address[] memory messenger,
uint[] memory amount
) external payable returns (uint[] memory phtlcIDs) {
}`

Can you please add this in your questions by editing the same ?

Also, can you share the function’s permalink of Etherscan ?

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x4ea1C936E3167B6CdF553Ce94FE9BCb6e9B756aa#code
